# django unique object (not unique field)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-2.2

how to make a unique object (not unique per field)

## e.g:

name : honda

category : car

#### success

name : honda

category : bike

#### success

name : honda

category : bike

#### failed coz all field have same value to another object

if i use `unique` at the field, the second case will be failed, coz honda (name) already created

my code :

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127,unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)         

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django provides a Meta option called unique together which seems to satisfy this use case:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [[“name”, “category”]]
```

Django docs indicate though that this may be deprecated and recommend the more fully featured UniqueConstraint meta option

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        UniqueConstraint(fields=[“name”,”category”], name=“unique_object”)
    ]
```

Comment: thanks bro, maybe better if you add `from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint`

Comment: This is new in Django 2.2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Meta class with unique_together attribute: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['name', 'category']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: The docs do say this may be deprecated and recommend using constraints => UniqueConstraint

Answer (score 0):

If you are using save

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127,unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)         

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    # Here is save
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
      # Whatever you need to do
      if not Brand.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.name).exists():
        super(Brand, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

In my case

```
class Category(models.Model):
name = CICharField(max_length=255, unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This category has already been registered."})

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    # return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)) )
    return reverse('home')

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    self.name = self.name.lower()
    self.name = capitalizeFirtChar(self.name)
    # If the name already exists
    if not Category.objects.filter(name__iexact=self.name).exists():
        super(Category, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```